# need to convert US recipe calling for tomato sauce to equivilant in UK

Tags: substitutions, sauce, tomatoes

I have a wonderful chili recipe that calls for 16 oz. of tomato sauce and need help finding an equivilant for my dear friend in the UK who wants to make this recipe. Is there a way she could delute a tube of tomato puree (similar to our tomato paste) to get the proper consistency and flavor? I'd appreciate any help with this. Thanks!!!

Comment: See also:  http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/29174/what-is-the-difference-between-tomato-puree-paste-and-sauce?rq=1

Comment: Which kind of tomato sauce does the recipe call for? You can get either "tomato sauce" as in a seasoned sauce to put on pasta or pizza, or "tomato sauce" (usually in smaller cans) that's basically just cooked tomatoes, pureed, and very minimally seasoned.

Answer (score 4):

Tell your friend to buy around a 450g jar of *passata*. This is finely crushed, sieved tomatoes. It comes plain, or most supermarkets carry versions with onions, basil etc.

Tomato puree is an entirely different thing and I wouldn't go down that route.

There are also various pre-made tomato sauce jars available from the likes of brands like *Dolmio* that have various flavour combinations. Depending on the ingredients in the tomato sauce you use, one of those may be more appropriate. They tend to be thicker and more heavily seasoned and flavoured than straightforward passata.

Comment: US canned tomato sauce is a fully cooked product, possibly seasoned.

Comment: In that case I'd go for the Dolmio or Ragu option.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than buying a 'tomato sauce' or something close, you might just [make your owns sauce](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/alton-brown/tomato-sauce-recipe/index.html) from fresh tomatoes. This will inevitably improve the quality of the sauce and the chili.